# Tirei a senha da Janela de Login do Elementary 5, como recolocar

Tags: release-hera

Boa tarde. Instalei o Elementary 5 criando uma senha para o setup, que é chato, logo no in[icio do simbolo do elemntary, e criei a senha do login antes de entrar na página inicial do sistema, na área de trabalho mesmo. **Resultado: quero trazer de volta a senha da página inicial do sistema, aquela do login, caso contrário o sistema inicia com a senha do setup mas pede a senha logo em seguida quando entro no chrome, por exemplo. É chato. prefiro trazer a senha novamente antes do login.** Como faço?

Agradeço quem puder ajudar.Abraços

Answer (score 0):

Teoricamente você consegue definir as senhas e quando elas devem ser requisitadas nas contas de usuários `Ferramentas do sistema -> Configuracoes -> Contas de usuario`. Lá você clica no seu usuário e define se quer pedir a senha no login ou logar automaticamente.

Sobre pedir a senha para cada aplicativo que abre, isso pode estar relacionado se você está fazendo login automático com o perfil de convidado. Se esse for o caso, você pode marcar para desabilitar o usuário convidado e logar automaticamente com um perfil de administrador.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Valeu meu Caro. Muito obrigado. Abraços.